# Trait type parameters inference

Tags: scala

Why can't the Scala compiler infer the type parameter `A` for `Y` as `Int`?

```
trait X[A]

trait Y[A] extends X[A]

object Foo extends X[Int] with Y
```

Is there a way I can do this where `Y` can know about the type parameter of `X` without specifying it twice in `Foo`'s declaration?  I couldn't get a self typing solution to work either.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have `object Foo extends Y[Int]`?

Comment: To expand on @LimbSoup's answer, since Y[A] already extends X[A], you are mixing in X[A] twice. Any particular reason why?

Comment: Fair question.  I will want several `Y` types, so I'm deferring to the compiler to linearize them in a reasonable way for me (which I think answers @Mario's question).

Answer (score 1):

For some use cases, using an intermediary class can solve the problem:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class XBase {
  type A
  def say(a : A) : Unit = println(a)
}

trait Y extends XBase {
  override def say(a : A) : Unit = { 
      println("Hello ")
      super.say(a)
  }
}

class X[B : TypeTag] extends XBase {
   type A = B
}

object Foo extends X[Int] with Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala does not support the inference (and omission) of type constructor parameters in type declarations. This might be possible in a future Scala version based on DOT calculus which tries to unify type parameters and type members.

See for example the slides of Odersky's talk [The Trouble With Types](https://github.com/strangeloop/StrangeLoop2013/raw/master/slides/sessions/Odersky-TroubleWithTypes.pptx) (slides 29ff).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have type parameter in this form? In some cases solution as following can be used:

```
trait X { type A /* type parameter as member */ }
trait Y extends X
object Foo extends Y { type A = Int /* equivalent to Y[Int] or X [Int] */ }
```

It could be used in definitions.

```
trait X {
  type A 
  def xfun: A
}
trait Y extends X { def tuple[K](k: K): (K, A) = (k -> xfun) }
object Foo extends Y {
  def xfun = System.identityHashCode(this)
  type A = Int
}
```

Then if testing:

```
scala> Foo.tuple("test")
res0: (String, Foo.A) = (test,2088931356)
```